# Can't get “fsck_hfs” to run on my MacBook while checking an external drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a 3TB Seagate GoFlex drive which shows up in “Disk Utility” but not on the desktop. Disk utility can’t repair it so I wanted to try `fsck_hfs`.

```
Last login: Fri Jul 31 00:22:20 on ttys000 
$ DISKUTIL LIST
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE          IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   
disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            250.1 GB      disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB    disk0s3
/dev/disk1
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
1:        Apple_partition_map                         262.1 KB   disk1s1
2:                  Apple_HFS FreeAgent GoFlex Drive  3.0 TB     disk1s3
/dev/disk2
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *16.8 MB    disk2
1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk2s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Flash Player            16.8 MB    disk2s2
```

I try to run it:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ sarah$ % sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk1s3
```

and I get:

```
-bash: fg: %: no such job
```

Does anyone know why it won’t run?

Comment: I read in an online forum (and tried it out and it worked) that you can remove a particular system file and the disk is then not checked and mounts, allowing files to be recovered. I wish I'd done it at the time because now I can't remember the name of the file. Any ideas what it might be?

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know why it won’t run?

The [`fsck_hfs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fsck_hfs.8.html) command should run, but your syntax is incorrect. That’s what this error is:

```
-bash: fg: %: no such job
```

So where does that `%` come from? And is it needed? Look at your command as entered:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ sarah$ % sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk1s3
```

Seems like you prepended a `%` in front of the command. In Bash that `%` means is a job control specification. And in the case you are showing, `%` represents—according [to this Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html):

> A single ‘%’ (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to
>   the current job.

But whatever it means—and why it threw up that “no such job” error—shouldn’t factor into `fsck_hfs` in anyway. I read that as a typo.

My guess is you copied and pasted the `fsck_hfs` command from some blog site or tutorial site where there is odd code formatting and such. Regardless, toss that `%`; it’s not needed in any way.

Knowing that, your command should be something like this:

```
sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk1s3
```

Hopefully that will repair the volume on the disk and bring it all back to life.